# Multiplayer including keyboard

Tags: just-shapes-and-beats

Last weekend, my cousin and I tried playing Just Shapes and Beats co-op mode, but we only had one controller available (XBOX360 USB controller for PC).

We couldn't find a way to assign the controller to player two, maybe because we didn't know how to.

Is it not possible (yet) to play the game with one player on the keyboard and another player on the controller?